# how do you show a metric (graph on the dashboard) of appdynamics that shows different values "per application"?

Tags: appdynamics

With appdynamics it's easy to setup metrics that "aggregate" data from different nodes.  What if you want to aggregate some date, and some other data, show as distinct lines in the graph? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you create the metric, then edit a dashboard, then click on a widget -> add metric -> (browse, but choose "Individual Nodes" instead of JMX, then select your metric. voila.